# How to order a collection

Tags: magento, collections

I have two tables. Table one contains primary values and table two contains secondary values. I have joined the tables and now need some way to order the collection and output those values. The values need to be in the order of:

```
Primary1
    secondary1
    secondary2
    secondary3
Primary2
    secondary4
Primary3
    secondary5
    secondary6
```

The secondary tables contains a foreign key to link to the primary table and I have joined them using the below statement

```
$areas = Mage::getModel('namespace_module/model')->getCollection();
$areas->getSelect()
      ->join(
        array('lr' => 'shop_locator_region'),
        'main_table.area_id = lr.area_id',
        array('region' => 'lr.name')
      );
```

The above returns all the required values but how do I go about taking the returned collection and ordering it?

these are the returned values when I use `var_dump`, `name` is the primary value `region` is the secondary value

```
array (size=4)
0 =>
array (size=4)
'area_id' => string '1' (length=1)
'name' => string 'UK' (length=2)
'region' => string 'Manchester' (length=10)
1 =>
array (size=4)
'area_id' => string '1' (length=1)
'name' => string 'UK' (length=2)
'region' => string 'London' (length=6)
2 =>
array (size=4)
'area_id' => string '3' (length=1)
'name' => string 'JAPAN' (length=5)
'region' => string 'Tokyo' (length=5)
3 =>
array (size=4)
'area_id' => string '2' (length=1)
'name' => string 'EUROPE' (length=6)
'region' => string 'Paris' (length=5)
```

After using various filters [found here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento) (and trying to understand what each was doing) and looking through the code base to see how the menus are generated I still havn't been able to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$areas = Mage::getModel('namespace_module/model')->getCollection();
$areas->getSelect()
      ->join(
        array('lr' => 'shop_locator_region'),
        'main_table.area_id = lr.area_id',
        array('region' => 'lr.name')
      )
->order('lr.PRIMARY_FIELD_NAME','ASC')->order('lr.SECONDARY_FIELD_NAME', 'ASC');

Comment: thats great, thanks it works. where do I add the `distinct(true)` so I don't repeat my values e.g. 'uk'. so far I have tried: before order(), after order() and after getSelect(). I am assuming distinct(true) will work